# Architecture Questions - The most scalable architecture for Maintenance of Record Triggered Flows

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I am looking to build a more scalable record trigger architecture with Salesforce flow. Right now I am finding that I cannot create one Master Flow to execute different before triggered events in Salesforce flow and that I need to create separate before the record is saved flows. This makes maintenance difficult because I have to create a new Flow every time I want to execute new automation.

I want to understand how others are creating scalable and intuitive architectures without having to create numerous before triggered record flows. Not being able to call sub-flows from record-triggered flows means I end up creating even more flows.

How are you creating one Record triggered flow that calls different branches/methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While previously this was not possible and it made it hard to build an architecture framework without needing Apex and invocable methods, winter 22 adds this important feature.

From the winter 22 release notes,

> Subflow elements are now available for record-triggered flows that run after a record is saved or before a record is deleted. Now you can break your automation into building blocks and reduce the complexity of a flow.

This is documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_subflows_record_triggered.htm&type=5&release=234).

You will have to wait for another month or so to get this rolled in production orgs.

Also, this will be a GA feature once launched so there is support for any bugs that will pop up. I strongly recommend to test this feature in sandbox before rolling to users.